# Google Payment Issue

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am developing an app that predicts the scores of AFL football.

I am planning on offering different levels of subscriptions.

We had planned on using Stripe as a payment gateway, but we cannot now as they deem us to be a satellite of gambling payments. A few other platforms take a similar view.

I cannot find any documentation regarding the use of the in house Google payment system in this regard?

Does anyone know if there would an issue using this to create subscription transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The service you need is called Google Pay. For Android refer to [this document](https://www.mobindustry.net/how-to-integrate-google-pay-into-your-android-app/)